# UnityEvent variable in custom editor

Tags: events, unity-game-engine, editor

Please help me how to show UnityEvent variable in custom editor.

Script:

```cs
public class BTNPattern : MonoBehaviour {
    public UnityEvent testEvent;
}
```

Editor script:

```cs
[CustomEditor(typeof(BTNPattern))]
public class BTNPatternEditor : Editor {
    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        BTNPattern myTarget = (BTNPattern) target;
        // what to put here to show myTarget.testEvent ?
}
```

Comment: It does show by default. No need for custom editor.

Comment: im using custom editor because of other variables and usefull way to work with its. Unity Event is just a problem, that appeared in my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change array size in Inspector variable in Unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165995/unable-to-change-array-size-in-inspector-variable-in-unity)

Comment: You can also draw the default inspector https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.DrawDefaultInspector.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way:

```
SerializedProperty sprop = serializedObject.FindProperty("testEvent");
EditorGUIUtility.LookLikeControls();
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(sprop);
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

Comment: I've removed all code that wasn't related to the Q, because OP was mixing another Q in the topic & reanswering in next answer.