# Unity-Monodevelop Variable Synching issue

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have added a C# Script to the Main Camera. I defined a variable `MyNumber` like below -

```
public int MyNumber = 9;
```

My problem is when I change the value of the variable; inside the Unity Editor it remains the same. For example if I change the value from 9 to 19 in the C# script file using Monodevelop, the Unity Editor continues to show My Number = 9 instead of 19; unless I reset the script file.

Please check the screenshot:
[image: Variable not syncing properly]

Comment: you *can not* use Capitals for variables names. you must change it to `int myNumber`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to change array size in Inspector variable in Unity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165995/unable-to-change-array-size-in-inspector-variable-in-unity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal behavior. There's no way for the Unity Editor to know if the old value of 9 was purposely changed in the editor from the default found within your C# script. So it plays it safe and assumes it was modified.

It's important to remember that the script initialized value represents a default value.  It does not always guarantee the starting value.  Case in point, it's updated in the editor.

Comment: A first-class answer, but the huge number of duplicates and clutter in the `Unity3D` tag is a real problem, unfortunately :/

Comment: @JaySoyer So this is the default behavior you are saying. Thank you.