# Unity C# make a variable editable in inspector and use it in other classes via AddComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a simple problem:

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {
    //Here is a variable that can be editable in the inspector
    public float A = 0f;
}
```

And in the inspector, I set `A` to `4.0`.

And now, in another class:

```
public class Goop : MonoBehaviour {
    void start () {
        GameObject Foom = GameObject.Find("FooManager");
        Foo Foolee = Foom.AddComponent<Foom_Manage> ();

        print (Foolee.A);
    }
}
```

Now, instead of writing to the console the correct number, `4.0`, it writes the original number `0` to the console, the number I used just as a placeholder. How can I use AddComponent to successfully get variable `A` to equal `4.0`?

Comment: GetComponent not AddComponent.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I mean, I don't know why, but it works. =D

Comment: Because GetComponent gets the existing component while AddComponent adds a new component.

Comment: NOTE!!  generally, it's critical in Unity that you DO NOT set a default value, on, public variables.  You must delete the " = 0f"

Comment: Here!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35166004/294884